# Recursive sum in Redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

```
CREATE TABLE testit (
  id INT, v1 INT, v2 INT, result INT);

INSERT
   INTO testit (id, v1, v2, result)
   VALUES 
     (1, 1,     2, 1 )
   , (2, 4,     3, 4 )
   , (3, 6,     7, 6 )
   , (4, NULL, 10, 13)
   , (5, NULL, 12, 25)
;
```

Given the first three columns id, v1, v2, I want to write a query that returns the 'result' column:

- v1 if v1 is not null
- the (recursive) sum of the preceding rows of v1 and v2 ig v1 is null (or alternatively: the last value of v1 and the sum of v2 between the first row where v1 is null and the preceding row)

Is this possible? [SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/c5007)

Comment: How did you calculate the result as 13 for id=4?

Comment: This would be simple with window functions or recursive CTEs but ParAccel (Redshift) has neither, AFAIK.

Comment: @JosephB 6+7 the above row v1+v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query gets you the desired result. 3 different queries return the following result sets joined together by `UNION ALL`:

if v1 of current row is not null

if v1 of current row is null and v1 of previous row is not null

if v1 of current row is null and v1 of previous row is null

```
select t_main.id, t_main.v1, t_main.v2, results.result
from 
testit t_main
inner join
(
  select id, result
  from testit
  where v1 is not null
  union all
  select t1.id, max(t2.v1+t2.v2) sum_result
  from testit t1 
  inner join testit t2 on t2.id = t1.id-1 and t2.v1 is not null
  where t1.v1 is null
  group by t1.id
  union all
  select
    to1.id, max(to3.v1+to3.v2+to1.v2)
  from testit to1
  inner join testit to2 on to2.id = to1.id-1 and to2.v1 is null 
  inner join 
  (
    select t1.id t1_id, max(t3.id) t3_id
    from testit t1 
    inner join testit t2 on t2.id = t1.id-1 and t2.v1 is null
    inner join testit t3 on t3.id < t1.id and t3.v1 is not null
    where t1.v1 is null
    group by t1.id
  ) max_id on to1.id = max_id.t1_id
  inner join testit to3 on max_id.t3_id = to3.id
  group by to1.id
) results
on t_main.id = results.id
order by t_main.id;
```

Performance-wise this query may not be the best approach, as there are so many self-joins, but there are quite a few business rules as well.

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/c5007/45)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The SQL expression is:

```
select ti.*,
       sum(coalesce(v1, c2)) over (order by id)
from testit ti;
```

I'm not 100% sure that Redshift supports cumulative sum without a `range` or `rows` option.  So this might be either:

```
select ti.*,
       sum(coalesce(v1, c2)) over (order by id range between unbounded preceding and current row)
from testit ti;
```

or:

```
select ti.*,
       sum(coalesce(v1, c2)) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from testit ti;
```

Apologies . . . I don't have access to RedShift right now.  It is sometimes finicky about the syntax that it accepts for windows functions.  But one of these three should work.

Comment: what you say does not work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/c5007/49
It sums all of v1 with the current row c2, whereas I want just the preceding v1 with the preceding v2 as per the result column in my example.